# Turn off cellular connection

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile, lumia-550

How can I turn off the cellular connection (-no phone calls) without tapping airplane mode?

I know how to turn off wi-fi without airplane mode, but I can't seem to find the same thing for the general cellular connection (including talk), only for cellular *data*.

Comment: Specify your version of Windows Mobile so someone may help you.

Comment: @mms911 His has tagged his question with windows-10-mobile. And this settings have remained the same in all versions of Widows 10, if that's what you are asking. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @KolappanNathan Sorry I haven't noticed these tags.

Comment: @mms911 It's okay.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn of Cellular connection by doing the following steps:

1. Go to *Settings->Network & Wireless-> Mobile & Sim*. Note - It will be *Cellular & Sim* for English US.
2. Near Sim 1 and Sim 2, you will find toggles to turn those SIM on and off.

[image]

As you asked this will turn of the entire cellular connection including talk, sms and mobile data.

Comment: I see **Cellular & SIM** not **Mobile & SIM**, and the only toggle button there is for **Data connection** under **Cellular data**.

Comment: @ispiro **Cellular & SIM** will be the name if you use English(US) or similar language as display language. I use English(India) hence it is **Mobile & SIM** for me. And regarding the toggle button it is present there. I have **added a screnshot** to make things clear. Just take a look at my updated answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. This is very strange. I don't have that on my phone. Perhaps it's only available on dual-sim phones (as yours obviously is)?

Comment: @ispiro Perhaps. Yes, My phone is a dual sim phone.If that is the case I suggest you give a suggestion in Windows Feedback.